# Как выгрузить ресурс (drawable) из памяти?

Tags: android, android-layout, resources, drawable

[image: Layout]

Нa layout автоматически прокручиваются кнопки, на каждую кнопку присвоен свой drawable ресурс который закрашивает ее. Drawable на кнопки помещаются не сразу, а во время прокрутки. Проблема в том что они занимают много памяти. 
Есть ли способ выгружать их из памяти по мере надобности?

Пытался присваивать null, но на память это не влияло :( `RG_SSButton.setBackgroundResource(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RG_SSButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Этого должно быть достаточно. `GC` освободит память когда нужно сам

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. А если по делу, то перешел на Picasso для более рационального использования ресурсов.